# Excel sorting by multiple grade letter

Tags: microsoft-excel

Thank you for reading.
I want to sort excel data by grade..
Example :

```
Ryan   A   B   C
Mel    B   C   C
Roy    A   A   B
```

And the result will become :

```
Roy
Ryan
Mel
```

Roy goes to top because he got more As, and B and so on

Thanks to ALL, especially Mark Fitzgerald, Rajesh 
S and robinCTS

This is the real data will look like, with the marks and grade will be on the sheet as well..

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Updated to match the OP's worksheet.

---

It's possible to solve this with a just a single helper column:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Enter the following formula in `K5` and ctrl-enter/copy-paste/fill-down into `K5:K8`:

```dart
=SUMPRODUCT(($B5:INDEX(5:5,COLUMN()-1)={"A";"B";"C"})*(COLUMNS($B5:$J5)-1)^{2;1;0})
```

Then just sort the table by the `Score` column, largest to smallest.

If the number of grade columns never changes (which it looks like they won't in your case), or you don't mind manually adjusting the formula if they do, the following simpler formula can be used:

```dart
=SUMPRODUCT(($B5:$J5={"A";"B";"C"})*5^{2;1;0})
```

The `5` in this formula is one more than the number of grade columns.

**Explanation:**

The formulas work by creating and summing an array of weighted grades.

**Notes:**

- The first formula automatically adjusts if grade columns are added or deleted.
- The second formula also automatically adjusts unless a column is inserted immediately to the left of the the `Score` column.
- Both these formulas can be modified to allow for more grades, for example, to add a "D" grade, change the `{"A";"B";"C"}` to `{"A";"B";"C";"D"}`, and the `{2;1;0}` to `{3;2;1;0}`

Comment: Hi..i think i understand this and its work. Just when Y got 1 A with 9 Cs, and X got 10 Bs, X on the higher ranks..which i hope Y on the higher ranks because he got an A. A always on the higher ranks. Thanks man.

Comment: @cliffe You're welcome. I'm going to update the answer with a more comprehensive explanation to help you understand it better. I'll let you know when I do so. PS Now that you've reached 15+ reputation you can also upvote any/all answers (including the accepted one) that ***actually work*** and were helpful. You do this by clicking the upwards pointing triangle at the top-left of the answer. This is how you say thanks, and rewards the answerer with reputation. You can also upvote questions that you find helpful.

Comment: Hi @robinCTS, ya I already click it. Thanks. FYI, i just using the second formula (simpler one)in ur solution..hope can get some explanation on the first one, which i think is more useful if the column will change. Tq so much man.

Answer (score 1):

In this screen shot, the formula in E2 can be copied to the other Score cells.  The total of the Scores can then be sorted in descending order to get your rankings.

[image: Sort by Grades]

The `CHOOSE(MATCH(E$1,$E$1:$G$1,0),3,2,1)` returns 3 in this particular formula because `Score A` is in the 1st position of the 3 headings.

Comment: Would whoever made the down vote care to explain why?

Comment: Hi mark. What if, cindy got 1 A and 3 Cs, and the total is 6, and Linda got 4 B, and the total is 8. I actually need cindy on the higher ranks, because he got A. Its like olympic medal, whoever got Gold, on the higher position..although the opponent get 100 silver. Thank you Mark.

Comment: Mark, your answer doesn't actually work. I suspect that may have been the reason for the downvote.  A better question to ask would be "Would the three users who made the upvotes care to explain why they upvoted an answer that doesn't work?" ;-) As cliffe has pointed out you are incorrectly weighting the grades. It doesn't even work for the three grade example let alone when extended for the general case. If Ryan's grades were `ACC` and Mel's grades `BBB`, how would your formula rank them?

Comment: @robinCTS the answer was valid for the original question.  I agree that it doesn't work following the significant OP edit about 3 hours ago which really changed the whole requirement from simply ranking based on 3 grades to ranking such that a single A will always trump BBB.  That wasn't in the question when I answered, as you well know.

Comment: I hate to burst your bubble (especially viz-a-viz your claim to be able to telepathically read my mind), but you are totally wrong. *"Roy goes to top because he got more As, and B and so on"* has appeared in *every single revision* including the original post. It can *only* be interpreted as, well, Roy goes to top because he got more As. I ask again, if Roy's grades were `ACC` and Mel's grades `BBB`, would your formula rank Roy above Mel? The main reason I jumped in with may answer after two had already been posted was that I saw two non-working solutions to an obvious and simple problem. …

Comment: …  (The other reason, of course, was that  my solution only required one helper column.) PS I expect an apology when/if you finally realise you are in the wrong. And just so you are aware *"as you well know"* can be interpreted as a belligerent statement and is typically used as such. If that was not your intent you should have followed it with a appropriate emoticon. Better yet would be to simply avoid such potentially inflammatory remarks.